# Render "0" value using a mustache template

Tags: javascript, templates, web-applications, mustache, zero

I have a model with a attribute with a value of "0" (zero).  My template looks something like this:

```
    {{#count}}{{{count}}} items{{/count}}
    {{^count}}-{{/count}}
```

If `myModel.count = 0`, the rendered html is nothing. It's like the value "count" is null and not null at the same time.

Mustache documentation for this case: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#inverted-sections

Comment: What version are you running? I found your issue on github and it was supposedly fixed in a commit 3 months ago. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/188 -> See hswolff's comment.

Comment: the latest version helped. it now goes to the negative case. but I still can't display a zero.

Comment: Just a hunch, but could you try `{{{ count }}}` or `{{& count}}`

Comment: It won't display a zero because zero is falsey. One option to get it to display is to set it to a non-falsey value (like the string `'0'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bobthecow answered it in his comment:

> It won't display a zero because zero is falsey. One option to get it
>   to display is to set it to a non-falsey value (like the string '0')

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a lambda to check the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bodman/yb83s/

```
var data = {

  "dataset" : [ 
    {count: 0},
    {count: -1},
    {count: 2},
    {count: false},
    {no_count:'yay'}
  ],


  "check_zero": function () {
    return function (text, render) {
      var result = '';
      var count = this.count;
      if(!isNaN(parseFloat(count)) && isFinite(count)){ 
          result = count;
      }else {
          result = render(text);
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not clean but works

```
{{#data.value}}
    {{data.value}}
{{/data.value}}
{{^data.value}}
    0
{{/data.value}}
```